# How to add a camera to turtlebot?

Tags: turtlebot, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to the world of hardware, ports, pins and stuff. We bought a turtlebot3, I wonder if how can we add a camera on it. Can I just bought a camera for raspberry pi like this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Raspberry-Pi-Camera-Module-Megapixel/dp/B01ER2SKFS/ref=sr_1_3?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1502212966&sr=1-3&keywords=raspberry+pi+camera](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ER2SKFS) and write a node basically listening to image data sending from the port of camera and publish it? Is this the right(easy) way to achieve my goal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268329/how-to-add-a-camera-to-turtlebot?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It really depends on what you want to do with your camera.

It's for example very likely that you will want to add your camera to the [tf tree](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) of your robot.

Why ? Because to use your camera data alongside other sensors you will need to position each of the sensors in one similar coordinate framework. (example: [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) can build a 3D map of an environment using RGBD camera, Odometry and 2D laser data, but in order to combine this data, you have to position each of the sensors in a common framework: this framework is often completed with what you will find in the wiki articles, in the **"Required tf Transforms"** and **"Provided tf Transforms"** sections)

How to do that ?

You can for example [broadcast a tf](https://answers.ros.org/question/57355/how-do-i-setup-a-static-tf/), or edit the [urdf file](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file) of your robot. For the turtlebot 2, here are some information about how to find the [urdf files](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_description).

On the other hand, if you plan on doing image processing using open CV, you don't need to do that to use your camera. If the camera is not already supported by a ROS Package (understand: not launched with a ROS node and its data seen through a ROS message topic being published), you'll need to connect it yourself with a new package to the ROS network.

---

Originally posted by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) with karma: 127 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1